# How do you find the inverse function of $f(x)=e^{2x}+4x^3$?

Tags: inverse-function

So the first thing I found is if the function is one-to-one, because we know that if it is there is a inverse function of that function:

I found the derivative of the function:  $f'(x)=2e^{2x}+12x^2$ where $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (-∞,∞)$ which implies that the function is one-to-one.

We have then per definition that the inverse function is given by:
$$y = f^{-1}(x) \impliedby x = f(y)$$

so we define that $x = f(y) = e^{2y}+4y^3 \implies \ln(x) = 2y\ln(e)+ 3\ln(4y)$

I dont find a way to solve this equation for $y$. Have I done this correctly or?

Sorry for any grammar or spelling mistakes, english is not my first language. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just because a function is elementary it does not mean its inverse is elementary. Look up the Lambert $W$-function for instance.

Comment: You have made a mistake in your manipulation since $\ln (a+b)$ does not simplify, you assumed $\ln(e^{2y}+4x^3) = \ln\,e^{2y}+\ln(4x^3)$ which it does not. remember $\ln(ab)=\ln \, a + \ln \, b$

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

> $$x = f(y) = e^{2y}+4y^3 \implies \ln(x) = 2y\ln(e)+ 3\ln(4y)$$

**False**. It is not true, in general, that $\ln(a+b)=\ln a + \ln b$. In fact, what $\ln a + \ln b$ is equal to $\ln ab$, not $\ln(a+b)$.

---

In general, inverses of functions such as yours are rarely elementary functions, which means it is unlikely that there exists a "nice" way of writing the inverse of your $f$.

Comment: Apologies I hadn't seen your answer until I added my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can judge, the following equation has no analytical solution:

$$e^x+x=n$$

So, your equation $e^{2x} + 4x^3$, which is more complicated than yours, can't be inversed.